# How to Get row by key value or visible index in ASPxGridView then change column value?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

Hi
In ASPxGridView, is there a way to get a row by its VisibleIndex or KeyValue so that I can change any column value in it?, I mean something like this:

```
var row = myGrid.SelectRowByKeyValue(myKeyValue);
OR:
var row = myGrid.SelectRowByVisibleIndex(myKeyValue);  

row["Column1"] = true;
```

**Edit:**
What I'm tring to do is that every time I hit the button I want to check one specific row (I'm using ajax to not reload all the page);

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myGridView.VisibleRowCount; i++)
{
 if ( [My condition] )
   {
     (
       (CheckBox)myGridView
         .FindRowCellTemplateControl(i,
                                     myGridView.Columns["MyColumnName"] as GridViewDataColumn,
                                     "My_Unbound_Control_Name"
                                    )
     ).Checked = true;
   }
}
```

I's may not be the right way to do it but I couldn't solve it another way.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the [ASPxGridView.GetRow()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetRowtopic) method.  NOTE, that changing the value in the DataRow is not enough.  If you want these changes to be preserved, save them to the DB.

Since you are using unbound columns, you should handle the CustomUnboundColumnData event and provide modified data for this row within this event handler.  The common approach is described in the [Providing Data for Unbound Columns](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3765) topic.  If this does not help, please describe in greater details.

**UPDATE**

Your approach is incorrect.  The ASPxGridView does not provide a method to set a text of a certain cell (TD).  Instead, you should force the grid to raise the CustomUnboundColumnData event.  This can be done using the ASPxGridView's DataBind method.  In this event handler, you should determine the KeyField value of the processed row, compare it with the keyField value of the row where the button was clicked and return the required value.  This is how I would implement this feature...

Comment: thank you, but this method gives me the entity of this row..I just want the row it self because I'm using unbound column in the grid that doesn't have property in the entity.

Comment: I'll try to make it clear..what I'm trying to do is this (pseudo code):
for (int i = 0; i < myGridView.VisibleRowCount; i++) { if(myGridView.Rows[i].Cell[2].Value == true) {myGridView.Rows[i].Cell[3].Value == 3;}
........ the way you mentioned doesn't trigger at all I don't know why..I just click a button then post back happened and in the button code I change the column value I want.